# hibernate second level cache with hazelcast implementation, collection elements are not retrieved from the cache but from the database

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, orm, hazelcast, second-level-cache

I have a "strange" behaviour with the second level cache that do not hit the elements of a collection from the cache but from the database.

There are three classes to modelize a ManyToMany relationship with attributes between an user and a group.

The Person class from which User and Group classes inherit :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "userType", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Person implements Serializable {
...
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class User extends Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    protected Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<>();
}


@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("2")
public class Group extends Person {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    protected Set<UserGroup> users = new HashSet<>();

}
```

The userGroup class that map the intermediate table with additional attributes

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserGroup implements Serializable, Ientity<PkUserGroup> {

    @EmbeddedId
    @NotNull
    private PkUserGroup id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idGroup", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
    private Group group;

    ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        UserGroup userGroup = (UserGroup) o;
        return id.equals(userGroup.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }

}
```

The embeddable key for the UserGroup class ID

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public class PkUserGroup implements Serializable {

    private Long idUser;
    private Long idGroup;

}
```

All the entities and the collections are configured to be cacheable.

I made a test where I retrieve an user in the DB from his ID, then I make a get on the UserGroup collection and hibernate generated the query because of the Lazy mode configuration.
I did that several times in a loop.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void level2QueryCacheSelectTest() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        Optional<User> oUser = this.userRepository.findById(1l);

        User user = oUser.get();

        logger.info(user.toString());

        for (UserGroup ug : user.getUserGroups()) {
            logger.info(ug.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Hibernate generate two select at the first iteration as expected, then it uses the first level cache and print the same results.

the user request :

```
select
    user0_.id as id2_1_0_,
    user0_.name as name7_1_0_,
    ...
from
    users user0_ 
where
    user0_.id=? 
    and user0_.user_type=1
```

the userGroups retrieved using the id of the user only, the elements of the User.userGroups collection

```
select
    usergroups0_.id_user as id_user2_6_0_,
    usergroups0_.id_group as id_group1_6_0_,
    ...
from
    user_group usergroups0_ 
where
    usergroups0_.id_user=?
```

Here the result in the second level cache that I can see with Hazelcast mancenter.

[image]

The user is a member of 4 groups so there are 4 entries as expected in the oauth2.domain.UserGroup region, and 1 collection in the oauth2.domain.userGroups region.

Now the second execution of the test where things are going wrong :)

At the first iteration of the test, Hibernate makes 4 queries into the UserGroup table using the id of the user and the id of the group. So he can retrieve the collection in the cache (because he already knows the id of the group) but not the elements of the collection that are supposed to be in the  oauth2.domain.UserGroup region.

```
    select
        usergroup0_.id_group as id_group1_6_0_,
        usergroup0_.id_user as id_user2_6_0_,
    from
        user_group usergroup0_ 
    where
        usergroup0_.id_group=? 
        and usergroup0_.id_user=?

binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [9]
binding parameter [2] as [BIGINT] - [1]
```

same for the 3 other UserGroup

Now in the cache I have 8 UserGroup elements

[image]

I'm not sure why the elements are not found in the cache, I implemented the hashcode and equals of the UserGroup class using the embedded ID. But I'm not sure how Hazelcast does the job so maybe there is a misconfiguration. If you have any idea how can I solve that issue you're welcome.

Versions :

Hibernate : 5.3.12.Final

Hazelcast-hibernate53 : 1.3.2

Hazelcast : 3.12.3

Spring boot : 2.0.0.RELEASE

Here is the Spring-boot config of Hazelcast and jpa.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://mysql-server:3306/oauth2
        username: ********
        password: ********
        initialization-mode: never
    jpa:
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
        properties:
            hibernate:
                cache:
                    #required - turn on L2 cache.
                    use_second_level_cache: true
                    #optional - turn on query cache.
                    use_query_cache: true
                    hazelcast:
                      use_native_client: true
                      native_client_address: hazelcast-member:5701
                      native_client_group: *********
                      native_client_password: *********
                    region:
                      factory_class: com.hazelcast.hibernate.HazelcastCacheRegionFactory
                format_sql: true
                #optional - generate statistics to check if L2/query cache is actually being used.
                generate_statistics: true
```

Comment: Can you show your `application.properties|yml` file?

Comment: @Cepr0 of course I added up the config for Hazelcast and Jpa

Comment: Strange ... the settings seem to be correct. Perhaps the problem is in the complex entity schema. Or maybe the reason is that your implementation of the `hashCode` in `UserGroup` is not entirely correct - when you use `Set` for the '-toMany' associations, then it's beter to use this [approach](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/).
And take a look at my [repo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-hazelcast-hibernate-l2c-demo) - I hope it will be useful.

Comment: The test method I used is a junit test. It throwed a LazyInitializationException so I added a @Transactional annotation at the method level to make it work. And that is the origin of the problem, I made test in my application in real time and without that annotation it works as expected. In my Set I never add any elements with null ids so I don't think it's a problem, I don't realy agree with the trick that the hashcode should always return the same value, because that value is used to retrieve remove or add an element fast. (~O(1) ) . Thanks for the repo I will take a look at it ;)